# C++20 : Making reverse iterator from custom iterator fails

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer, c++20

I'm making a reverse iterator from my custom iterator on my B-Tree implementation, but it fails to work.

Full code : https://wandbox.org/permlink/hrM32RYb6oVHDHAm

My iterator implementation:

```
class BTreeIterator {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        
        Node* node;
        std::vector<T>::iterator it;
        
        void Increment() {
               // ...
        }
        
        void Decrement() {
              // ...      
        }
        
    public:
        BTreeIterator(Node* node, std::size_t i) : node {node} {
            assert(node && i <= node->key.size());
            it = node->key.begin() + i;
        }
        
        reference operator*() const {
            return *it;
        }
        
        pointer operator->() const {
            return it;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator& operator++() {
            Increment();
            return *this;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator operator++(int) {
            BTreeIterator temp = *this;
            Increment();
            return temp;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator& operator--() {
            Decrement();
            return *this;
        }
        
        BTreeIterator operator--(int) {
            BTreeIterator temp = *this;
            Decrement();
            return temp;
        }
        
        friend bool operator==(const BTreeIterator& x, const BTreeIterator& y) {
            return x.node == y.node && x.it == y.it;
        }
        
        friend bool operator!=(const BTreeIterator& x, const BTreeIterator& y) {
            return !(x == y);
        }
    };
```

My typedef declaration in `class BTree`:

```
    using iterator = BTreeIterator;
    using const_iterator = BTreeConstIterator;
    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    iterator begin_;
    const_iterator cbegin_;
    iterator end_;
    const_iterator cend_;

// ... 

    reverse_iterator rbegin() {
        return reverse_iterator(end_);
    }
    
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const {
        return const_reverse_iterator(cend_);
    }
    
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const {
        return const_reverse_iterator(cend_);
    }
    
    reverse_iterator rend() {
        return reverse_iterator(begin_);
    }
    
    const_reverse_iterator rend() const {
        return const_reverse_iterator(cbegin_);
    }
    
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const {
        return const_reverse_iterator(cbegin_);
    }
```

The compiler complains for this reason:

`error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'std::reverse_iterator<BTree<int, 2>::BTreeConstIterator>::reference' {aka 'void'}`

The standard gives (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

Until C++20, `std::reverse_iterator<Iter>::reference` had been equal to `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::reference` (In my case, `T&`)

Since C++20, `std::reverse_iterator<Iter>::reference` has been changed to
`std::iter_reference_t<Iter> = decltype(*std::declval<Iter&>())`
It seems to became `void` in my case, causing the error.

My questions:

1. What is the rationale behind changing a reference type of a derived reverse iterator?
2. Why my `BTreeIterator` type is not referenceable? `decltype(*std::declval<BTreeIterator&>())` gives `void`. How can I change it to `T&`?

Comment: Where does it say that? I think this question would benefit from a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @bitmask Sorry, the reproducible example couldn't be minimal, because this error seems to depend on my iterator implementation. You could see the compiler output from the attached link of code.

Comment: Problem solved, ```BTreeIterator``` was not referencable because it is ```class``` with ```private``` members. Changing it to ```struct``` solved the problem. Ugh, why it is so hard to find this restriction in the standard spec. Grrr.

Comment: My bad. I'm not really sure where that problem is, but have you considered making the type definitions of your iterator type public?

Comment: If the member types are private then nothing can use them. So why define them in the first place?